# More pythonic way to write this block (and elimnate: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required)

Tags: python

I have this (which works):

```
def make_key(x):
    return "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(x.f1, x.f2, x.f3)

def make_value(x):
    return (x.f7, x.f1, x.f4, x.f9, 
            x.f2, x.f8, x.f10, x.f11, x.f12, x.f17, 
            x.f18, x.f19, x.f14, x.f15,
            x.f16, x.f17, x.f20)

row_data = {}
    for x in records:
        key = make_key(x.f1,x.f2,x.f3)
        value = make_value(x)
        row_data[key] = value
```

I tried this:

```
row_data = dict([(make_key(x), make_value(x))] for x in records)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Edit:

`records` is a list of objects that have field properties **f1, ...fn**

Answer (score 5):

You need to drop the list wrapper; just produce the tuples:

```
row_data = dict((make_key(x), make_value(x)) for x in records)
```

You were producing a list with one element each, a tuple.

If you are using Python 2.7 or newer, you can also use a dictionary comprehension:

```
row_data = {make_key(x): make_value(x) for x in records}
```

Your `make_value` could be expressed by using a [`operator.itemgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

make_value = itemgetter(
    'f7', 'f1', 'f4', 'f9', 'f2', 'f8', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f17', 
    'f18', 'f19', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f20')
```

The `make_key()` function can make use of the fact that you can pull out attributes from an object; `{0.f1}` would interpolate the `f1` attribute of the first positional argument to the `str.format()` method; make use of this to create a bound `str.format()` method that takes just one positional argument:

```
make_key = '{0.f1}/{0.f2}/{0.f3}'.format
```

Answer (score 0):

A few different things you can do to make it simpler :)

No need for a separate make_key function definition, you already have one:

```
make_key = '{0.f1}/{0.f2}/{0.f3}'.format
```

Beyond that, depending on your Python version you can also use dict comprehensions:

```
row_data = {make_key(x): make_value(x) for x in records}
```